# How to prove that $\frac{\ln 12}{\ln 18}$ is irrational witout using the change of base rule?

Tags: logarithms, fractions, rationality-testing

I have to show that $\frac{\ln 12}{\ln 18}$ is irrational by using [change of base rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base).

At the beginning I have proved that $\ln r$ is irrational for any rational $r$, $r\ne 1$. Then using this we can say that $\ln 12$ and $\ln 18$ are irrational.

But from here it is difficult for me to show that the fraction is irrational knowing that both the numerator and the denominator are irrational.

> How to prove that $\frac{\ln 12}{\ln 18}$ is irrational without using change of base rule?

Comment: $$\dfrac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt3}=?$$ or $$\frac\pi\pi=?$$

Comment: What's the meaning of “$a$ and $b$ are coprime”? I see none.

Comment: Sorry for that 'in general'. Please now have a look at the question.

Comment: @egreg They don't have any common factor.

Comment: Anyway, even if you could prove the claim, that would not solve your given task because you'd not use the change of base rule.

Comment: @Singh Unfortunately this means nothing as well.

Comment: @Singh : I'm curious, what are the factors of $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @Tryss Sir in the answer by WSL you can see that a and b are having a common factor as $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Singh : and $a$ and $b$ have $\frac{a}{b}$ as a "common factor". You really need to explain what you means by "common factor" for real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove it using that the quotient of irrationals is irrational for the simple reason that the statement is false.

You may instead use a different strategy: suppose
$$
\frac{\ln 12}{\ln 18}=\frac{2\ln2+\ln3}{\ln2+2\ln3}=\frac{a}{b}
$$
for positive and coprime integers $a$ and $b$. Then
$$
2b\ln 2+b\ln3=a\ln2+2a\ln3
$$
that becomes
$$
(2b-a)\ln2=(2a-b)\ln3
$$
which tells you that $\ln3/\ln2$ is rational as well. By the change of base rule, this is the same as saying that $\log_23$ is rational, so
$$
\log_23=\frac{h}{k}
$$
for positive integers $h$ and $k$. Therefore
$$
3=2^{h/k}
$$
or
$$
3^k=2^h
$$
that's impossible because of unique factorization of integers.

Comment: Sir when we are required to show that $\sqrt{3] + \sqrt{2}$ is irrational then we take the square of it and then show that the sum is irrational. In my question can that be done without base change rule?

Comment: @Singh Unfortunately not: $\ln2$ and $\ln3$ are not only irrational, but transcendental. So no algebraic operation such as raising to an integer power or taking roots can bring them to amenable forms.

Comment: Sir in my problem the base is $e$ and so it is not possible to show the irrationality with base change rule. But is this possible to show the irrationality of $\frac{ln_218}{ln_312}$

Comment: @Singh Sorry, but I don't understand: I proved that $\ln12/\ln18$ is irrational, didn't I?

Comment: Sir I'm asking (1)You said that ln 2 is transcendental and this is because e is transcendental and so it is not possible to show that ln 3/ln 2 without base change rule. (2) $\frac{ln_218}{ln_312}$ is not transcendental so can it be proved irrational without using base change rule?

Comment: @Singh (1) Basically so. (2) For this you just need to use that $\log_23$ is irrational, but you need the base change rule as well.

Comment: I think your exponent for the $2$ at the end should be $h$ and not $k$.

Comment: @Clayton Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is in general not true. For example $a = 2\sqrt{2}, \: b= \sqrt{2}$.

then $\frac{a}{b}= 2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{a}b = \dfrac{\ln{12}}{\ln{18}} = \log_{18}{\!12}\iff\!\! \begin{align}18^{a/b} &= 12\\ 18^a&=12^b\end{align}$ $\iff \begin{align}2^a3^{2a}=2^{2b}3^b\\ 2^{a-2b}=3^{b-2a}\end{align}$ $\iff\begin{align} a-2b &= b-2a\\ 3a&=3b\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow \end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

Let x be an irrational number.

Obviously $\frac{x}{x} = 1$.

And also, suppose  any nonzero integer multiple of $x$, let $b=mx$.

$\frac{b}{x}=\frac{mx}{x}=m \in \mathbb{Z}$ is also irrational.

So it is not always true.